# Dimensions of a spectral representation

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

I'm currently trying to perform analysis of a spectrogram, with the use of PCA.
I'm confused about what the dimensions of the result should therefore be. Currently, the dimensions are: `451x128`. But I thought that it was a standard image, and therefore it should have 2 dimensions.

Comment: what result are you referring to?

Comment: @geometrikal Hey - I'm referring to the STFT results. The dimensions are: 128x128 it's making it difficult to determine the Eigen values/vectors any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It *does* have two dimensions. An image of size $N \times M$ has two dimensions. Three dimensions would be $N \times M \times L$, and so on. For each pixel with coordinates $x$ and $y$, in two dimensions, you have a spectrum magnitude value.

However, if you start treating rows or columns of your spectrogram as vectors, then you're interpreting them as 451 points in 128-dimensional space or 128 points in 451-dimensional space. This is different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically, I have this: `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` which would therefore infer $N x M$ right? I'm just computing the eigen values and vectors and still getting the same as if I had a matrix which looked like: 

$ M = [1 2; 3 4]$ does this make sense?

Comment: How are you computing them?

Comment: I calculate the cov matrix of the spectrogram and then using the standard equation: $$\frac{a+b\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c^2)}}2.$$ calculate the eigen values. I get a 2x2 matrix of eigen values. Do you want an example? I understand what you mean about the 2x2 and this equation should work. I just don't see how I can validate this. I'm computing PCA by the way!